# Breadth first c

Tags: c, unix, breadth-first-search

How would I implement a breadth first traversal of a directory(depth unknown and not necessarily symmetrical).

My first thought was using fork. I am not sure how to implement it. I was thinking a loop that would first get the parent/s, then's get the number of children of those parents, then forks so many times based on how many children and chdir to that child, which since multi-processes were made all children are then chdir'd to. Then return the children as parents to be forked.

I feel like there are possible hole's in this and I am looking for input on possible flaws or is this a terrible approach. I have heard about people using fork with breadth first, but never found any examples, so if you have any I would gladly look at them.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will look like:

1. Set initialize `todo` queue with the base directory.
2. While the `todo` queue isn't empty,

   1. Assign the head of the queue to `path`.
   2. Remove the head of the queue.
   3. If `path` references a directory,

      1. Append the path of the files in `path` to the `todo` queue.
   4. Perform whatever action you want to perform with `path`.

I don't see why you think `fork` would help.

---

For example, actual Perl implementation:

```
sub dir_contents {
   my ($path) = @_;

   my $dh;
   if (!opendir(my $dh, $path)) {
      warn("Can't open dir \"$path\": $!\n");
      return;
   }

   return map { "$path/$_" } grep { !/^\.\.?/ } readdir($dh)
}

my @todo = 'some path';
while ( my $path = shift(@todo) ) {
   if (!stat($path)) {
      warn("Can't stat \"$path\": $!\n");
      next;
   }

   push @todo, dir_contents($path) if -d _;

   print("$path\n");
}
```

Comment: I get that it's best not to use fork() for this(i've heard of people doing it with it), but it would be more helpful to see this in c, maybe using the sys/queue.h.

Comment: Sure, you can add parallelism using `fork`, but then it wouldn't be breadth-first. I can remove the Perl code if it makes you feel better. As for your problems using sys/queue.h, you know how to ask. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.